# How to get CSR Value from KeyChain Access

Tags: certificate, keychain

So...probably a dumb question but I followed the instructions [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

And I'm trying to upload my CSR to digicert where the format is suppose to look like this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIICvDCCAaQCAQAwdzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxDTALBgNVBAgMBFV0YWgxDzANBgNV
BAcMBkxpbmRvbjEWMBQGA1UECgwNRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jLjERMA8GA1UECwwIRGln
aUNlcnQxHTAbBgNVBAMMFGV4YW1wbGUuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG
9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA8+To7d+2kPWeBv/orU3LVbJwDrSQbeKamCmo
wp5bqDxIwV20zqRb7APUOKYoVEFFOEQs6T6gImnIolhbiH6m4zgZ/CPvWBOkZc+c
1Po2EmvBz+AD5sBdT5kzGQA6NbWyZGldxRthNLOs1efOhdnWFuhI162qmcflgpiI
WDuwq4C9f+YkeJhNn9dF5+owm8cOQmDrV8NNdiTqin8q3qYAHHJRW28glJUCZkTZ
wIaSR6crBQ8TbYNE0dc+Caa3DOIkz1EOsHWzTx+n0zKfqcbgXi4DJx+C1bjptYPR
BPZL8DAeWuA8ebudVT44yEp82G96/Ggcf7F33xMxe0yc+Xa6owIDAQABoAAwDQYJ
KoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAB0kcrFccSmFDmxox0Ne01UIqSsDqHgL+XmHTXJwre6D
hJSZwbvEtOK0G3+dr4Fs11WuUNt5qcLsx5a8uk4G6AKHMzuhLsJ7XZjgmQXGECpY
Q4mC3yT3ZoCGpIXbw+iP3lmEEXgaQL0Tx5LFl/okKbKYwIqNiyKWOMj7ZR/wxWg/
ZDGRs55xuoeLDJ/ZRFf9bI+IaCUd1YrfYcHIl3G87Av+r49YVwqRDT0VDV7uLgqn
29XI1PpVUNCPQGn9p/eX6Qo7vpDaPybRtA2R7XLKjQaF9oXWeCUqy1hvJac9QFO2
97Ob1alpHPoZ7mWiEuJwjBPii6a9M9G30nUo39lBi1w=
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

But I just get a CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest file after using Keychain Access and when I try to upload it to digicert I get an error that it's an invalid file type but I'm not sure how to find the content within ------BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST---- and ---END CERTIFICATE REQUEST----

I've also tried uploading the .p12 file...but nope

Comment: It would be helpful if you expressed what your question is. There are multiple ways of looking at this post.

Comment: What command do you use to generate the CSR?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you have generated the CSR in a binary format, e.g. DER.  You need to convert it to PEM format (Privacy Enhanced Mail) in order to get it to be readable and come with those ---BEGIN  tags etc.

DigiCert, as you mentioned is your vendor, has a helpful tool for helping generate CSRs from the command line: https://www.digicert.com/easy-csr/openssl.htm

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I asked a question as a guest so I can't comment or choose an answer sorry, but I used the openssl command in my terminal using the link that Herringbone_Cat provided